Microsoft Photo Viewer: scroll through photos by date
When organizing photos on Windows 10, I like to scrolling through them using Microsoft Photos using the forward / back arrows. In this case the sequence seems jumbled because the alphabetical order jumps around chronologically, and despite loading photos from File Explorer sorted by date, Microsoft Photos does not match the sorting. Chatgpt suggested batch renaming the files with date first, but would first like to ask about any possible fixes or toggles for changing the sorting with the forward / back arrows in Microsoft Photos.

Microsoft's Photos app does not have a way to change or customize the scroll order. You have two options: use a different photo viewer, or rename your files based on date.
Note if you choose to change dates: you'll need to use YYYYMMDDHHMMSS (or a 2 digit year should work as well) in order for this to work properly.
